# creating a nested json file from variables using jq

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell, json, jq

I have a script where I am storing variables and using that I am trying to create a json output to a file.
here is my json build format

```
#!/bin/bash
JSON_STRING=$(jq -n \
                  --arg configId "$configid" \
                  --arg objectname "tempfile" \
                  --arg artifacts "[{ "name" : "oer", "version" : "$ot" }]" \
                  --arg test "2021" \
                   '$ARGS.named') > output.json
```

desired json o/p (output.json) -

```
{ "configId": "c8f", "objectname": "tempfile", "artifacts": [{ "name" : "oer", "version" : "1.01" }], "test" : "2021"}
```

here I am not getting the desired output.
any help would be great

Comment: jq in itself has very little to do with Unix/Linux. Not saying it's off-topic here, but that with StackOverflow there might be a larger community with more JSON / `jq` experts.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd do it in 2 steps: (EDIT: artifacts is an array of objects)

```bsh
inner=$(jq -n --arg name oer \
              --arg version "$ot" \
              '$ARGS.named'
)
final=$(jq -n --arg configId "$configid" \
              --arg objectname "tempfile" \
              --arg test "2021" \
              --argjson artifacts "[$inner]" \
              '$ARGS.named'
)
echo "$final"
```

```json
{
  "configId": "c8f",
  "objectname": "tempfile",
  "artifacts": [
    {
      "name": "oer",
      "version": "1.01"
    }
  ],  "test": "2021"
}
```

Add a `-c` if you want the final output to be one line.

---

Comment: but my output desired output in the question has array braces after `artifacts` How do I create that ?

Comment: @Alex in this case, use `'[$ARGS.named]'`  for the first `jq`.

Comment: @Alex, missed that, fixed.

Answer (score 3):

The safest way to create JSON on the command line is through using a tool that constructs it for you as `jq` does.  However, since you have a nested structure, you may want to create that sub-structure in a separate call to `jq` as is [shown by glenn jackman](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/676667/493832).

Another way to do what they show, but in one go:

```bsh
jq -n \
    --arg configId "$configid" \
    --arg objectname tempfile \
    --argjson artifacts "$( 
        jq -n \
            --arg name oer \
            --arg version "$ot" \
            '$ARGS.named'
    )" \
    --arg test 2021 \
    '$ARGS.named'
```

We use `--argjson` rather than `--arg` to include the JSON document from the inner `jq`, as it is a JSON document and not a string that needs encoding.

You could also use `jo`, which may reduce typing a bit,

```bsh
jo  configId="$configid" \
    objectname=tempfile \
    artifacts="$( jo name=oer version="$ot" )" \
    test=2021
```

A description of the  `jo` utility is found here: https://jpmens.net/2016/03/05/a-shell-command-to-create-json-jo/

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to "jo".

Answer (score 2):

You are not getting output because you are saving the output in a variable, so there is nothing to redirect to a file. You can do either this:

```
variable=$(command)
```

or this:

```
command > file
```

But you cannot do `variable=$(command) > file` because there is nothing to redirect. So although the above will run and wil create and/or overwrite `file`, the file will always be empty since you have already saved the command's output in a variable.

So, if you both want to have the output in a variable and save it to a file, you would need something like this:

```
JSON_STRING=$(jq -n \
                  --arg configId "$configid" \
                  --arg objectname "tempfile" \
                  --arg artifacts "[{ "name" : "oer", "version" : "$ot" }]" \
                  --arg test "2021" \
                   '$ARGS.named')
printf '%s\n' "$JSON_STRING" > output.json
```

Comment: No but the output comes like this have you noticed `"artifacts": "[{ name : oer, version : 1.01 }]" ` I dont want to have double quotes around the array braces rather I would have them in "name" "oer" "version" "1.01"


 -------CURRENT O/P-------->    "configId": "c8f", "objectname": "tempfile", "artifacts": "[{ name : oer, version : 1.01}]","test": "2021"

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want `artifacts` to be treated as a JSON array. If that's the case, use `--argjson` instead of `--arg` and fix your quotes:

```
jq -n \
  --arg configId "$configid" \
  --arg objectname "tempfile" \
  --argjson artifacts "[{ \"name\" : \"oer\", \"version\" : \"$ot\" }]" \
  --arg test "2021" \
   '$ARGS.named'
```

This should result in:

```
{
  "configId": "",
  "objectname": "tempfile",
  "artifacts": [
    {
      "name": "oer",
      "version": "1.01"
    }
  ],
  "test": "2021"
}
```